# C# massive insertion into data structures

Tags: c#

In C#, you can do the following:

```
List<int> registers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

This will produce a list with 1, 2, 3, and 4 in the list. Suppose that I am given a list from some function and I want to insert a bunch of numbers like the following:

```
List<int> register = somewhere();
register.Add(1);
register.Add(2);
register.Add(3);
register.Add(4);
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this like the snippet above?

Comment: I'm quite disappointed, I expected something *massive* `:P`

Comment: Yeah, if you're hardcoding truly massive insertions with collection initializers, that's TDWTF material.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the new items are in some kind of enumerable form already, the [`AddRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method allows you to add them all in one go:

```
var toBeAdded = new int[] { 1,2,3,4 };
register.AddRange(toBeAdded);
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
List<int> register = somewhere();
register.AddRange(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

Comment: Note that while your example is syntactically cleaner it won't offer any performance advantages as the collection initializer will still add the items one by one.

Comment: To add to DrJokepu's comment: the specific problem is that while calling Add multiple times (what collection initializers are syntax sugar for) will always resize the internal array more than once if you happen to have enough elements (probably 30+), AddRange *may* perform only a single resize even in those cases. If you use an array initializer instead, there won't be any resizes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest you can get is this:

```
List<int> register = somewhere();
register.AddRange(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

However, it may not always be possible to implicitly type the array.